# RSS feed including post updates

Tags: functions, rss

I am building a Wordpress site which has a number of fixed listings in the form of custom post types. Custom fields on these listings are updated every so often. I would like to create an RSS feed so subscribers are notified when a listing is updated. Currently it seems RSS only reflects new posts. Is there a function I can write to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

what you could possibly do, is set up a post dedicated to the list, then on the post / page do an include to retrieve that list onto it.

```
<?php
$my_id = 7 <---this would be the post / page id you set up on for the     list;
$post_id_7 = get_post($my_id, ARRAY_A);
$title = $post_id_7['post_content'];
?>
```

The rss feed you could set up to only show updates to that list, and the list could be included on the other posts / pages.